Why does Stack Exchange forcibly remove my double-space after a full stop? You're erroneously correcting my punctuation!
I've posted a question and found that Stack Exchange is messing up my punctuation.  There is supposed to be a double-space after a full stop, so why the punctuation fascism approach on this site?

I've read somewhere that using ( ) can be used to add an extra space.  ( ) That's just annoying and didn't work for me, can't you just back off with the auto-correction?


How many spaces come after a period?
It is generally agreed that having only one space after a period or punctuation mark is correct.


While some may believe that either way is right, Microsoft formally settled the space debate in 2020 and sided with everyone who thinks one space is correct, not two. The creator of Microsoft Word updated the software so that two spaces between sentences would be considered an error.


These days most contemporary style guides also recommend using a single space between sentences, including:



The Chicago Manual of Style
The American Psychological Association (often referred to as “APA”)
Microsoft Manual of Style
The Gregg Reference Manual
The Associated Press Stylebook


Reference: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/spaces-after-period/#:~:text=It%20is%20generally%20agreed%20that,space%20is%20correct%2C%20not%20two.

This is not a Stack Exchange thing, it is an HTML thing. No web browser has ever displayed double spaces in between sentences in rendered HTML, because HTML strips out superfluous whitespace.
The double space between sentences is an artifact from typewriters which did not have any concept of kerning. If you are typing on a computer in a web environment, you should objectively not be using double spaces, because they have never been supported.
Please let typewriter habits die!
